# About Architecture Application

Tags: android, architecture, view, fragment

I have a technical problem about my architecture. I explain my goal with this project.
I want to create a modular application. So I have created several modules; some have a UI and others do not.

My UI application is divided in three parts:

- one part, is the header, which display hours and some technical information
- another part is a list view where we can select the module to display.
- the final part is  the content of the module or the default screen.

So I tried to explore fragment where each item of my listview is a fragment. According to user's click, I load and display the view of the module in the content.

Each module do its treatment when it receives a intent from a broadcast.

An other idea, is to create, one view per module and attach this view to my current view (not create dynamically but with an xml).

I am so confused with the type of architecture to use.

If anyone has suggestions.

Comment: with architecture, do you mean a set of design patterns to use or, in a broader sense, the relationships between your modules?

Comment: The communication between the module is done with broadcast. Each module has a broadcast receiver with several intentFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal use for fragments. The guide [topic on fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) explains the general approach and also discusses [FragmentLayout.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.html), which is part of the [API Demos sample project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have implemented this but, when I "load" a new fragment with a click on the listview, my fragment appear on the other fragment. It's the code, when I load the fragment FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

         OtherFragment otf= new OtherFragment();
         ft.replace(R.id.detailFragment, otf);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();